# Don't start a thread in ASGI django while in manage.py

Tags: python, django, asgi

I am using Django 4.0.1 with the [channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/) extension, so I'm using the ASGI interface.

In one of my applications, I'm using it's [AppConfig.ready()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/applications/#how-applications-are-loaded) method to start a thread / asnyc loop - specifically the paho.mqtt package via [loop_start()](https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/#loop-start-loop-stop). If a message arrives on a subscribed topic, this application handles some business logic.

This works fine for my usecase - with the exception of two problems:

1. It's also started when I use any `manage.py` command.
2. `./manage.py runserver` (with reload enabled) will spawn a second process, which results in two connections being made - and I only need one.

While I could use a filesystem-mutex to block the execution of a second application, I'd like to know, if there's a more "Django way" of solving this?

Comment: Start the loop in a separate process/script, it's a bad idea to do it on app ready since your setup could expand to include several processes. Create a management command that starts your process and call this separately

Comment: @IainShelvington this makes a docker setup a lot harder due to a multi-process setup... isn't there any way to differentiate between a manage.py-command and an asgi process from inside django?

Comment: Run a separate container, if you are using compose create a duplicate service with a different command

Comment: while this does solve problem 1, it does not solve problem 2. I could wrap the runserver in my own file watcher for development, but I still can't believe, that there is no way of solving this in Django itself.